# Hibernate 6.3.1 Final getting NoClassDefFoundError for org/hibernate/type/descriptor/converter/spi/EnumValueConverter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/type/descriptor/converter/spi/EnumValueConverter
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3373)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3578)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2754)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.getConstructor(ReflectHelper.java:350)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeBeanInstanceProducer.produceBeanInstance(TypeBeanInstanceProducer.java:34)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeBeanInstanceProducer.produceBeanInstance(TypeBeanInstanceProducer.java:53)
- at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringBeanContainer.createBean(SpringBeanContainer.java:208)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringBeanContainer.getBean(SpringBeanContainer.java:124)
at org.hibernate.resource.beans.internal.ManagedBeanRegistryImpl.getBean(ManagedBeanRegistryImpl.java:110)
at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.setExplicitCustomType(BasicValue.java:825)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.BasicValueBinder.fillSimpleValue(BasicValueBinder.java:1238)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SetBasicValueTypeSecondPass.doSecondPass(SetBasicValueTypeSecondPass.java:26)
```

Note: I am using Hibernate Core 6.3.1 Final.
And hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62:3.5.3
Dependency
I am seeking assistance to resolve this issue. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

- Thank you!

Comment: Looks like your Spring version isn't compatible with Hibernate 6.3.1. Tried the same version of Hibernate with Spring Boot 3.1.3/Spring Framework 6.0.11 last week and ended up switching back to Hibernate 6.2.8.

Comment: @Karsten - how did you switch back to hibernate 6.2.8 ?

Comment: I'm using Maven. In Eclipse I checked which Hibernate dependencies are drawn by Spring (with spring-boot:3.1.3: hibernate-core:6.2.7 and hibernate-commons-annotations:6.0.6). Because there wasn't a newer version for the annotations lib I only added hibernate-core:6.2.8 to my pom.